# How to build SQL query for this following scenario?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, date

I have a table that looks like this:

```
Name    Post       Like Share   Comment Date
--------------------------------------------
Sita    test data 1 5   2   4   28/4/2015
Munni   test data 2 5   2   5   27/4/2015
Shila   test data 3 1   3   1   22/4/2015
Ram     Test data 4 5   0   5   1/4/2015
Sam     Test data 5 4   0   2   2/4/2015
Jadu    Test data 6 1   5   2   30/3/2015
Madhu   Test data 7 5   0   4   10/4/2015
```

Now I want my result set like this:

```
Type            Name      Post      Like  Share Comment Date
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
Today           Sita    test data 1    5    2   4       28/4/2015
Last 7 Days     Sita    test data 1    5    2   4       28/4/2015
Last 7 Days     Munni   test data 2    5    2   5       27/4/2015
Last 7 Days     Shila   test data 3    1    3   1       22/4/2015
Last 30 Days    Sita    test data 1    5    2   4       28/4/2015
Last 30 Days    Munni   test data 2    5    2   5       27/4/2015
Last 30 Days    Shila   test data 3    1    3   1       22/4/2015
Last 30 Days    Ram     Test data 4    5    0   5       1/4/2015
Last 30 Days    Sam     Test data 5    4    0   2       2/4/2015
Last 30 Days    Jadu    Test data 6    1    5   2       30/3/2015
Last 30 Days    Madhu   Test data 7    5    0   4       10/4/2015
```

Today must have only today's post. Last 7 days must have today's post + last 7 day's post. Last 30 days column must have all the post of last 30 days.

Comment: Look at using `union all` with `where` clauses...

Comment: can u please give the whole query ? please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of unions with different case statements to get the date range would work.

Comment: I am using this following query to track down date .... 

SELECT
  tblWatchList.UserName,
  tblPost.Post,
  tblPost.Time
FROM
  tblPost INNER JOIN tblProfile ON (tblProfile.ID=tblPost.UID)
   INNER JOIN tblWatchList ON (tblWatchList.ID=tblProfile.UID)
  WHERE dbo.tblPost.Time BETWEEN (SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),DATEADD(DD, DATEDIFF(DD, 0, GETDATE()), -44),120))
  AND GETDATE()
 ORDER BY FBDB.dbo.tblPost.Time ASC

Answer (score 0):

Use `union all` and `dateadd`:

```
select 'Today' as Type, Name, Post, [Like], Share, Comment, [Date]
from yourtable
where [Date] = getdate()
union all 
select 'Last 7 Days' as Type, Name, Post, [Like], Share, Comment, [Date]
from yourtable
where [Date] >= DateAdd(day,-7,getdate())
union all 
select 'Last 30 Days' as Type, Name, Post, [Like], Share, Comment, [Date]
from yourtable
where [Date] >= DateAdd(day,-30,getdate())
```

BTW, terrible choice for column names (don't use reserved words).